# Using "<" for input redirection of a file with commands that already handle files

Tags: shell, input-method

Regularly, I have seen the following syntax:

```
awk 'stuff' <file
sort <file
```

The thing is, I usually write:

```
awk 'stuff' file
sort file
```

And things work perfectly. So if both syntaxes are roughly equivalent (or are they?), is there any benefit from using `<file` syntax ?

**EDIT**

Existing threads cover some of my interrogations (using `<` implies that the shell opens the file *first* and *then* passes it as standard input to the command), but I feel that some remain:

- POSIX compliancy ?
- Is it to dissipate any ambiguity concerning the nature of `file` argument ?
- Is it specific to a certain type of shell ?
- Is it considered deprecated ?
- Performance-wise, is there a notable difference ?
- Any example where you would use one against the other is welcome.

Comment: The links you provided do hold some answers, (notably that both syntaxes do not behave the same), but my particular question covers a larger scope I think. Should I still accept duplicate status and close it ?

Comment: I have edited the question to enlarge the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Either will work if the command supports reading from standard input (the `command <file` form) or from a named file in the argument list. Even `tcsh` supports `command <file` so that syntax is fairly portable; whether a given command can read a file in the argument list (or standard input) depends on the command; `ed(1)` for instance reads commands from standard input, so cannot read a file from standard input.

At the C level, a command that reads from standard input or a named file will be doing something like

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fhandle;

    // option processing here ...

    if (argc == 0 || strncmp(*argv, "-", (size_t) 2) == 0) {
        fhandle = stdin;
    } else {
        if ((fhandle = fopen(*argv, "r")) == NULL)
            err(1, "could not open '%s'", *argv);
    }

    // read from fhandle here, which is either from stdin or a file ...
}
```

Some commands demand the `command -` form to indicate a read from standard input, others will do so automatically (as in the abovesaid code) when the argument list is empty. Otherwise, the code in either case will be dealing with `fhandle`, and does not care where the input is coming from (unless an error message needs to include the filename, but that can be stuck into an additional variable).

Comment: Does that mean that the file is read twice when using input redirection ?

Comment: some commands that handles filename arguments sometimes treat those arguments specially. like `awk` and the filename `foo=bar`, awk

Comment: Also yes I am aware some commands cannot take files as arguments, hence redirection through `<` is the only available option, but the question is more about why would you use redirection on commands that do not need it because they handle files natively ?

Comment: @ValentinB. what gave you the idea the file was read twice? It is not.

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable in these matters, but I was under the impression that for the file to be accessible in `stdin` it had to be read. This is most probably a rookie misconception on my part.

Comment: @ValentinB. the `stdin` and `fhandle` variables are pointers to a file; the read of the contents will happen subsequent to the figuring out of whether the input is from stdin or a named file. This is not shown in my code, as the read is exactly the same in either the standard input or named file case.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. That sounds pretty logical now that you say it.